# How to select option using PHP AJAX

Tags: php, html, function

I have this kind of proplem that is my select option is not working properly. The first select option that i created cannot functioning properly. Only the 'jabatan' option didnt work while the others can. When i try to search 'jabatan' and click 'cari' button, it didn't work.

```
function listAset($PK_lokasiaset,$jbtn,$bhgn,$pnmptn,$naset){
$where = "";
if($PK_lokasiaset == "") $where = "";
else $where = "WHERE PK_lokasiaset = '".$PK_lokasiaset."'";

if($jbtn != ''){
    if($jbtn == '99'){}
    else if($where == ""){ $where = "WHERE loak.FK_jabatan = '".$jbtn."'";}
    else $jbtn .= " AND loak.FK_jabatan = '".$jbtn."' ";
}
if($bhgn != '99'){
    if($where == ""){ $where = "WHERE loak.FK_bahagian = '".$bhgn."'";}
    else $where .= " AND loak.FK_bahagian = '".$bhgn."' ";
}
if($pnmptn != '99'){
    if($where == ""){ $where = "WHERE loak.FK_penempatan = '".$pnmptn."'";}
    else $where .= " AND loak.FK_penempatan = '".$pnmptn."' ";
}
if($naset != '99'){
    if($where == ""){ $where = "WHERE loak.FK_aset = '".$naset."'";}
    else $where .= " AND loak.FK_aset = '".$naset."' ";
}

$sql = "SELECT PK_lokasiaset,loak.nosiri,loak.FK_jabatan,loak.FK_bahagian,loak.FK_penempatan,loak.FK_aset,jab.namajabatan AS jabatan,bah.namabahagian AS bahagian,pen.butiran AS penempatan,kat.namaaset AS kategori,klas.namaaset AS klasifikasi,aset.namaaset AS naset
FROM lokasiaset loak
LEFT JOIN jabatan jab ON jab.PK_jabatan = loak.FK_jabatan
LEFT JOIN bahagian bah ON bah.PK_bahagian = loak.FK_bahagian
LEFT JOIN penempatan pen ON pen.PK_penempatan = loak.FK_penempatan
LEFT JOIN aset ON aset.PK_aset = loak.FK_aset
LEFT JOIN klasifikasiaset klas ON klas.PK_klasifikasiaset = aset.FK_klasifikasiaset
LEFT JOIN kategoriaset kat ON kat.PK_kategoriaset = aset.FK_kategoriaset ".$where." ORDER BY nosiri ASC";

$_SESSION['sqlaset'] = $sql;
//echo $sql;
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if($query) return $query;
else return mysql_error(); }
```

My html looks like this code

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" action="senaraiaset.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="row"> 
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="form-group">

                         <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Jabatan</label>
                         <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                         <select name="jabatan" class="form-control" onChange="showbhgn(this.value)">
                         <option value="99">-- Pilih --</option>
                         <?php
                         $sjab = "SELECT * FROM jabatan ORDER BY kodjabatan ASC";
                         $qjab = mysql_query($sjab);
                         while($rjab = mysql_fetch_array($qjab)){
                         ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $rjab['PK_jabatan']; ?>"><?php echo $rjab['namajabatan']; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                         </select>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Bahagian </label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" id="bahagian">
                         <select name="bahagian" class="form-control">
                         <option value="99">-- Pilih --</option>
                         <?php
                         $sjab = "SELECT * FROM bahagian ORDER BY kodbahagian ASC";
                         $qjab = mysql_query($sjab);
                         while($rjab = mysql_fetch_array($qjab)){
                         ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $rjab['PK_bahagian']; ?>"><?php echo $rjab['namabahagian']; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                         </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Penempatan </label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                         <select name="penempatan" class="form-control">
                         <option value="99">-- Pilih --</option>
                         <?php
                         $spen = "SELECT * FROM penempatan ORDER BY PK_penempatan ASC";
                         $qpen = mysql_query($spen);
                         while($rpen = mysql_fetch_array($qpen)){
                         ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $rpen['PK_penempatan']; ?>"><?php echo $rpen['butiran']; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                         </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Kategori Aset</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                         <select name="kategoriaset" class="form-control" onChange="showkat(this.value)">
                         <option value="99">-- Pilih --</option>
                         <?php
                         $sjab = "SELECT * FROM kategoriaset ORDER BY PK_kategoriaset ASC";
                         $qjab = mysql_query($sjab);
                         while($rjab = mysql_fetch_array($qjab)){
                         ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $rjab['PK_kategoriaset']; ?>"><?php echo $rjab['namaaset']; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                         </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Klasifikasi Aset </label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" id="kategoriaset">
                          <select name="kategoriaset" class="form-control"  onChange="showaset(this.value)">
                         <option value="99">-- Pilih --</option>
                         <?php
                         $sjab = "SELECT * FROM klasifikasiaset ORDER BY PK_klasifikasiaset ASC";
                         $qjab = mysql_query($sjab);
                         while($rjab = mysql_fetch_array($qjab)){
                         ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $rjab['PK_klasifikasiaset']; ?>"><?php echo $rjab['namaaset']; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                         </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Nama Aset </label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" id="namaasets" >
                          <select name="namaaset" class="form-control" >
                         <option value="99">-- Pilih --</option>
                         <?php
                         $sjab = "SELECT * FROM aset ORDER BY PK_aset ASC";
                         $qjab = mysql_query($sjab);
                         while($rjab = mysql_fetch_array($qjab)){
                         ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $rjab['PK_aset']; ?>"><?php echo $rjab['namaaset']; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                         </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>

                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="submit" name="cari" value="Cari" class="btn btn-primary" />
                      <input type="button" name="reset" value="Semula" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>
                 </div>

                 <br>

                <div class="row">
                <table id="datatable-fixed-header" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Bil</th>
                      <th>Kod Aset</th>
                      <th>Kategori Aset</th>
                      <th>Klasifikasi Aset</th>
                      <th>Penempatan</th>
                      <th>Jabatan</th>
                      <th>Bahagian</th>
                      <th>Nama Aset</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php
                    //$jbtn = '';
                    //$bhgn = '';
                    //$pnmptn = '';
                    /*$kat = '';
                    $klas = '';
                    $naset = '';*/
                    if(isset($_POST['cari'])){
                        $jbtn = $_POST['jabatan'];
                        $bhgn = $_POST['bahagian'];
                        $pnmptn = $_POST['penempatan'];
                        //$kat = $_POST['kategoriaset'];
                        //$klas = $_POST['klasifikasiaset'];
                        $naset = $_POST['namaaset'];
                    }
                    $query = listAset('',$jbtn,$bhgn,$pnmptn,$naset);//,$klas,$kat
                    //echo '-'.$query;
                    $bil = 0;
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        $bil++;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $bil; ?></td>               
                      <td><a style="color:#6197d0;" class="" href="asetAct1.php?aset=<?php echo $row['PK_lokasiaset']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nosiri']; ?></a></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['kategori']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['klasifikasi']; ?></td>                          
                      <td><?php echo $row['penempatan']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['jabatan']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['bahagian']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['naset']; ?></td>                          
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: It looks awfully like you will end up with multiple `WHERE` clauses in the final sql - as they say in Highlander `"There can be only one!"`

Comment: wow lot of left Joins there too.  if `$PK_lokasiaset == ""` then your query will fail.  I use an array for the where,  `array( PK_lokasiaset = '".$PK_lokasiaset."'", ... )` then do `WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where )`, also look into PLaceHolders,  SQL INJECTION

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager this is your issue

```
if($PK_lokasiaset == ""){
   $where = "";
}else{
   $where = "WHERE PK_lokasiaset = '".$PK_lokasiaset."'";
}
```

if that is empty, you get just

```
$where = "";
```

If it's not you get

```
 $where = "WHERE PK_lokasiaset = '".$PK_lokasiaset."'"
```

Subsequently you'll get

```
$where = "AND ...";
```

Without the word `Where` when it is empty, and your query will fail with

```
select * from table AND var = "something"
```

I would change this mess

```
if($PK_lokasiaset == "") $where = "";
 else $where = "WHERE PK_lokasiaset = '".$PK_lokasiaset."'";

if($jbtn != ''){
   if($jbtn == '99'){}
       else if($where == ""){ $where = "WHERE loak.FK_jabatan = '".$jbtn."'";}
       else $jbtn .= " AND loak.FK_jabatan = '".$jbtn."' ";
}
```

To something like this

```
  $where = array();

if($PK_lokasiaset != "") 
  $where[] = "PK_lokasiaset = '{$PK_lokasiaset}'";

    ...

if($naset != '99')
    $where[] = "loak.FK_aset = '{$naset}'";
```

And then just do

```
 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where );
```

And I would seriously use placeholders and prepared statements, to avoid SQL injection.  Which could easily be done as

```
 $params = array();
 $where = array();

if($PK_lokasiaset != "") {
    $where[] = "PK_lokasiaset = :PK_lokasiaset";
    $params[':PK_lokasiaset'] = $PK_lokasiaset;
}

...

if($naset != '99'){
    $where[] = "loak.FK_aset = :FK_aset";
     $params[':FK_aset'] = $PK_lokasiaset
}
```

Then with pdo you just do

```
   $stmt = $PDO->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where ));
   $stmt->execute( $params );
```

So much cleaner to use an array and implode.  The only time this won't work well is if you are mixing `AND` and `OR` in your query.